# Putting a "Like" button in an iOS App, iFrame?

Tags: ios, facebook, iframe, facebook-like

Within my native iOS app i have an iFrame that loads an external webpage. Putting a Like button on that page works fine when it's loaded from Safari etc., but when the page is loaded within the App, the Like button just doesn't appear.

Is this not possible?

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: The like button code is generated from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button ...works fine in regular browsers.

Comment: ...the app code I can't since I am not doing the app myself. Can it be related to how the webpage is loaded in the app?

Comment: where do you add the Like button to? UIWebView? Did you create separate class for the like button? or you just import it and addSubview to the UIWebView?

Comment: I don't know about addSubview, but the external page is defenately beeing loaded in UIWebView.

Comment: ...maybe it's impossible to have php, iframes etc. there.